# I got error Unable to locate factory for in laravel 8 app

Tags: laravel, laravel-factory

In Laravel 8.12 running factory from controller I got error :

```
InvalidArgumentException
Unable to locate factory for [App\Models\Secret].
```

app/Models/Secret.php :

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;


use DB;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Secret extends Model
{

    protected $guarded = [];
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('\App\Models\User');
    }

}
```

In database/factories/SecretFactory.php :

```
<?php

namespace Database\Factories;

use App\Models\Secret;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class SecretFactory extends Factory
{
    protected $model = Secret::class;

    public function definition()
    {
        return [
            'user_id' => 1,
            'secret' => $this->faker->test,
        ];
    }
}
```

and in app/Http/Controllers/Admin/DashboardController.php :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\Secret;

class DashboardController extends Controller
{
   ...


    public function test()
    {
        factory(\App\Models\Secret::class, 1)->create([]);
        ...
```

I installed

```
"laravel/legacy-factories": "^1.1",
```

Running commands :

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan  clear-compiled
composer dump-autoload
```

did not help

What did I miss ?
I run :

```
composer require laravel/legacy-factories
```

Have I to register it somewhere else?

Thanks

Comment: why did you install legacy factories if you are using the laravel 8 version of factories (not legacy)?

Comment: I found similar hint in internet. Is it wrong ? Whch steps have I to do ?

Comment: check the Laravel 8 docs on how to call factories and remove that package you installed ... https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database-testing#creating-models-using-factories https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database-testing#persisting-models